# Tcp/ip и osi. В чем разница и что их обьединяет?

Tags: osi

Tcp/ip и osi. В чем разница и что их обьединяет?

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP - практически применяемая модель. Она использует 4 уровня из 7 уровней модели OSI. Первый уровень TCP/IP объединяет первый и второй уровни OSI, последний -  три последних OSI.

Нагляднее, например,

[https://selectel.ru/blog/tcp-ip-for-beginners/#:~:text=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20TCP%2FIP%20(Transmission,%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82.](https://selectel.ru/blog/tcp-ip-for-beginners/#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20TCP%2FIP%20(Transmission,%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82.)

Comment: Ну, реально для программирующих на урове сокетов, TCP/IP вообще сужается до 2-х уровней -- transport и internet layers (все остальное этому программисту либо не видно (link layer), либо абстрактно (application layer))